# where to use virtual function here

Tags: c++, unix, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to create an imaginary and small unix hierarchy using inheritance and polymorphism.

I have a **class** named File and the class has the following data member:
-**string** name

And the class File suppose to have the following operations:
-function **path** (returns the path of the file)
-function **ls**   (similar to ls command)
-function **cd**   (similar to cd command)
-function **cp**   (copies the given file to the current file)

There are other classes that derive from the File class.
*The class Directory is a special File that can hold a number of Files in it.
*The class TextFile is a File that include text.

An example run in main function can be such as follows:

```
Direcrory mydir(“mydir”);
TextFile myText(“mytext”, ....);
mydir.cp(myText);
mydir.ls();
```

Here is the thing guys. I can implement this without inheritance and polymorphism. But I want it to be an Object Oriented. So I have two questions?
1-)I could not decide which function should be virtual.
2-)And How to implement path function without storing an extra data member

I am thinking about it for two days. But I could not find out such a good solution. If you help me, I would be very glad.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: objects don't have to have virtual functions in order to behave in "Object Oriented Style". virtual functions are tools in OOP, no the goals.

Comment: I don't think that the way you are going about this is correct. Firstly, in Unix and derived systems, you have a separation between a file and a directory entry (possibly one of many) referencing that file. Secondly, take for example your `cp` interface. Your hierarchy suggests that you can copy any (!) file, including a directory, to a text file and vice versa, which doesn't make sense. This is similar to the classic question concerning the inheritance relation between a circle and an ellipse, search the web for that and you will understand.

Comment: Okay but I a reusable code. I thought  that polymorphism can be good

Comment: Yes, polymorphism can be good. It can be bad, too, though.

Comment: No not vice versa. We can not copy a file to textfile. or cannot **cd** to text file. These operations suppose to be restricted.

Comment: So there is no "is a" relation between the baseclass "File" and the derived classes (Liskov Substitution Principle). In that case, why should they have a common baseclass if the supported interfaces differ anyway?

Comment: It seems like something forced implementation with inheritance. But I want it this way, because as I have learned having an abstract class is better in any situations. @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: if there is no "is a" relation between the baseclass "File" and the derived classes, how can be polymorphism or inheritance used? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: "I have learned having an abstract class is better in any situations." Blindly applying techniques is not going to make your programs better. If you tried to justify why it is better and how that applies to your case, you would quickly find out that this is simply not true.

Comment: I said this sentence because every file in unix is derived from one file.(At least I learned this way). Let's think about Java programming language, Every class is automatically derived from object class. @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: In what sense is every file in Unix derived from one file? Just because the filesystem has a single root doesn't mean that any derivation in the OOP sense takes place here. Further, just because Java forces all types to share a common baseclass doesn't mean that this is good or that it should be repeated in C++.

Comment: thanks for your answer @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1-)I could not decide which function should be virtual.

If you have the structure of `Base* parent = new Child()` and you want to call overrided methods of `Child` then these functions should be virtual. 
 if you have this structure - declare the destructor virtual.

> 2-)And How to implement path function without storing an extra data
>   member

Since a path is basically a string, you can just store the path in the parent class. return the string from `path` function and don't override this function in the Child classes. that's it. what is the problem with string few bytes of string?

In any doubt, just think "In real life, does it behave like it?"

Comment: firstly thanks for your answer.   Destructors are already virtual. But I think one of these functions suppose to be virtual.